# Lists defined as Maybe in Haskell? Why not?

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

You don't offen see `Maybe List` except for error-handling for example, because lists are a bit `Maybe` themselves: they have their own "`Nothing`": `[]` and their own "`Just`": `(:)`.
I wrote a list type using Maybe and functions to convert standard and to "experimental" lists. `toStd . toExp == id`.

```
data List a = List a (Maybe (List a))
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

toExp [] = Nothing
toExp (x:xs) = Just (List x (toExp xs))

toStd Nothing = []
toStd (Just (List x xs)) = x : (toStd xs)
```

What do you think about it, as an attempt to reduce repetition, to generalize?

Trees too could be defined using these lists:

```
type Tree a = List (Tree a, Tree a)
```

I haven't tested this last piece of code, though.

Comment: 'Sup dawg i heard you like Monads, so I put a Monad in your Monad …!
have you seen `Maybe String` it is actually of type `Maybe [Char]`, but I think you're reinventing Monad transformers (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) but I am not sure as I myself am not too familiar with monads right now.

Comment: Oh, I saw many `Maybe String` (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+%5BChar%5D)[here] but they have a different meaning. I just pointed out that `[]` is a kind of `Nothing` and stuff, so I thought about using `Nothing` to remove "re-definition".

Comment: It's not redefinition. List and Maybe have different semantics when used as monads. Also blurring the line and throwing away syntax sugar (especially list patterns) is downright stupid.

Comment: Syntactic sugars could still exist, it's easy to translate `[]` to `Nothing` when used with the datatype `Maybe List a`. However, I'm only talking about the theorical side.
The main problem comes from semantics... There is a parallel between lists and maybe, but there is nothing which is higher-order... In the same way `Bool` and DirectionHorizontal are similar, because their type constructors are antonyms, but you won't do `type Direction = Bool`, so we can't do `Maybe (List a)`.  I feel like something is missing.

Comment: [`stripPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:stripPrefix) -- take that!

Comment: It hurts! `stripPrefix :: Eq a => Maybe (List a) -> Maybe (List a) -> Maybe (Maybe (List a))`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All ADTs are isomorphic (almost--see end) to some combination of `(,)`,`Either`,`()`,`(->)`,`Void` and `Mu` where

```
data Void --using empty data decls or
newtype Void = Void Void
```

and `Mu` computes the fixpoint of a functor

```
newtype Mu f = Mu (f (Mu f))
```

so for example

```
data [a] = [] | (a:[a])
```

is the same as

```
data [a] = Mu (ListF a)
data ListF a f = End | Pair a f
```

which itself is isomorphic to

```
newtype ListF a f = ListF (Either () (a,f))
```

since

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

is isomorphic to

```
newtype Maybe a = Maybe (Either () a)
```

you have

```
newtype ListF a f = ListF (Maybe (a,f))
```

which can be inlined in the mu to

```
data List a = List (Maybe (a,List a))
```

and your definition

```
data List a = List a (Maybe (List a))
```

is just the unfolding of the Mu and elimination of the outer Maybe (corresponding to non-empty lists)

and you are done...

a couple of things

1. Using custom ADTs increases clarity and type safety
2. This universality is useful: see GHC.Generic

---

Okay, I said almost isomorphic.  It is not exactly, namely

```
hmm = List (Just undefined)
```

has no equivalent value in the `[a] = [] | (a:[a])` definition of lists.  This is because Haskell data types are coinductive, and has been [a point of criticism of the lazy evaluation model](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/the-real-point-of-laziness/).  You can get around these problems by only using strict sums and products (and call by value functions), and adding a special "Lazy" data constructor

```
data SPair a b = SPair !a !b
data SEither a b = SLeft !a | SRight !b
data Lazy a = Lazy a --Note, this has no obvious encoding in Pure CBV languages,
--although Laza a = (() -> a) is semantically correct, 
--it is strictly less efficient than Haskell's CB-Need
```

and then all the isomorphisms can be faithfully encoded.

Comment: How would you express non-regular data types, such as `data Tree a = Zero a | Succ (Tree (Node a))` where `data Node a = Node2 a a | Node3 a a a` (i.e. 2-3 tree)?

Comment: @Vitus You are right.  Polymorphic recursion is more complicated.

Comment: @Vitus.  I had to test this actually works: `newtype Mu2 (f :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *)) a = Mu2 (f (Mu2 f) a)` then you can define `data TreeF f a = ZeroF a | SuccF (f (Node a))` and `newtype Tree' a = Tree' (Mu2 TreeF a)`.   So you do need that higher kinded `Mu` operation, but this is non-essential (and I don't think you need anything higher than this, but I could be wrong).

Comment: If you instead use the corresponding functor combinators (Const, Id, +, *), you can throw in functor composition to get nested/non-regular data types.

Comment: @Conal. Nice. Another perspective is to allow for unrestricted use of `newtype` which gets you all the recursive schemes, a clean syntax for functions, and if you allow for RankN provides an encoding of GADTs using yoneda.  I thing yhe implicative fragment of second order intuitionistic logic is complete (via church encodings) though, so you don't even really need `(,)`, `Either`, etc.

Comment: @PhilipJF, Conal: Excellent! I somehow expected this to be possible using higher-kinded Mu combinator; it's just that "normal" Mu is useless here.

Comment: At the smallest level everything is defined in terms of bits, so it would ne interesting to see the different layers of abstraction that start from it and end up at List for example.
Maybe we could have more abstraction if we had more constraints on datatypes, such as the number constructors or the number of parameters. For example, we are allowed to write `data Possibility = Yes | No | NoneOfThese`. If we limited the number of data constructors to be of two, we would write `data Possibility = Maybe Bool`. Laos, we'd have to find how to keep this re-use of data-types while having "semantics".

Answer (score 9):

You can define lists in a bunch of ways in Haskell.  For example, as functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype List a = List { runList :: forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b }

nil :: List a
nil = List (\_ z -> z )

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons x xs = List (\f z -> f x (runList xs f z))

isNil :: List a -> Bool
isNil xs = runList xs (\x xs -> False) True

head :: List a -> a
head xs = runList xs (\x xs -> x) (error "empty list")

tail :: List a -> List a
tail xs | isNil xs = error "empty list"
tail xs = fst (runList xs go (nil, nil))
    where go x (xs, xs') = (xs', cons x xs)

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
foldr f z xs = runList xs f z
```

The trick to this implementation is that lists are being represented as functions that execute a fold over the elements of the list:

```
fromNative :: [a] -> List a
fromNative xs = List (\f z -> foldr f z xs)

toNative :: List a -> [a]
toNative xs = runList xs (:) []
```

In any case, what really matters is the **contract** (or **laws**) that the type and its operations follow, and the **performance** of implementation.  Basically, any implementation that fulfills the contract will give you correct programs, and faster implementations will give you faster programs.

What is the contract of lists?  Well, I'm not going to express it in complete detail, but lists obey statements like these:

1. `head (x:xs) == x`
2. `tail (x:xs) == xs`
3. `[] == []`
4. `[] /= x:xs`
5. If `xs == ys` and `x == y`, then `x:xs == y:ys`
6. `foldr f z [] == z`
7. `foldr f z (x:xs) == f x (foldr f z xs)`

**EDIT:** And to tie this to augustss' answer:

```
newtype ExpList a = ExpList (Maybe (a, ExpList a))

toExpList :: List a -> ExpList a
toExpList xs = runList xs (\x xs -> ExpList (Just (x, xs))) (ExpList Nothing)

foldExpList f z (ExpList Nothing) = z
foldExpList f z (ExpList (Just (head, taill))) = f head (foldExpList f z tail)

fromExpList :: ExpList a -> List a
fromExpList xs = List (\f z -> foldExpList f z xs)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could define lists in terms of `Maybe`, but not that way do.  Your `List` type cannot be empty.  Or did you intend `Maybe (List a)` to be the replacement of `[a]`.  This seems bad since it doesn't distinguish the list and maybe types.

This would work

```
newtype List a = List (Maybe (a, List a))
```

This has some problems.  First using this would be more verbose than usual lists, and second, the domain is not isomorphic to lists since we got a pair in there (which can be undefined; adding an extra level in the domain).

Comment: The empty list is `Nothing`! And the type is still `Maybe (List a)`. `Nothing` acts as `[]`. I separated the `Nothing` case on purpose, because it is already a data constructor of `Maybe`.
You're right; we can't have an empty list of type `List a`, and this new list is not identical to the standard one.

Comment: I don't like maybe and list having the same type.

Comment: No, they have the same semantics.  But we often want to introduce isomorphic data structures just to get different types.  For instance, a record type is isomorphic to a tuple, so we could always use tuples.  But that's not a good idea.  Differentiating different types is a good thing.

Comment: To differentiate record types and tuples, we could make the former a specialization of the later (though, I don't know how to do that).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a list, it should be an instance of `Functor`, right?

```
instance Functor List
  where fmap f (List a as) = List (f a) (mapMaybeList f as)

mapMaybeList :: (a -> b) -> Maybe (List a) -> Maybe (List b)
mapMaybeList f as = fmap (fmap f) as
```

Here's a problem: you can make `List` an instance of `Functor`, but your Maybe List is not: even if `Maybe` was not already an instance of `Functor` in its own right, you can't directly make a construction like `Maybe . List` into an instance of anything (you'd need a wrapper type).

Similarly for other typeclasses.

---

Having said that, with your formulation you can do this, which you can't do with standard Haskell lists:

```
instance Comonad List
  where extract (List a _) = a
        duplicate x @ (List _ y) = List x (duplicate y)
```

A Maybe List still wouldn't be comonadic though.

Comment: Is it a problem? We can still do `fmap (fmap (+2)) (toExp [1..3])`, which gives `Just (List 3 (Just (List 4 (Just (List 5 Nothing)))))`. With pattern matching, you can use the `List` directly.
Should `Maybe List` be considered the list or only `List`?

Comment: It's a problem if you need to pass your list to generic code that uses the typeclass instance. If you are using `List a` as a non-empty list of `a`s that's fine (and you can do things that you can't do with Haskell's standard lists). But if you're using `Maybe (List a)` as a possibly-empty list of `a`s it's a problem, because the typeclass instance attaches to the `Maybe`

Comment: Um, the composition of `Maybe` and `List` can be made into a `Functor`.  In fact, [any pair of `Functor`s can be generically made into one](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/packages/transformers-0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html).

Comment: @sacundim Sure you can, but then you don't have a `Maybe (List a)` any more, you have a `Compose Maybe List a`.

Comment: @L01man Yes, it's a problem because we have to double-fmap, and generic code we might like to use with it won't know that it has to double-fmap. With `Applicative` and `Monad` is more complicated.

Comment: @dave4420: I see what you mean, but then I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

When I first started using Haskell, I too tried to represent things in existing types as much as I could on the grounds that it's good to avoid redundancy.  My current understanding (moving target!) tends to involve more the idea of a multidimensional web of trade-offs.  I won't be giving any “answer” here so much as pasting examples and asking “do you see what I mean?” I hope it helps anyway.

Let's have a look at a bit of Darcs code:

```
data UseCache = YesUseCache | NoUseCache
    deriving ( Eq )

data DryRun = YesDryRun | NoDryRun
    deriving ( Eq )

data Compression = NoCompression
                 | GzipCompression
    deriving ( Eq )
```

Did you notice that these three types could all have been `Bool`'s?  Why do you think the Darcs hackers decided that they should introduce this sort of redundancy in their code? As another example, here is a piece of code we changed a few years back:

```
type Slot = Maybe Bool                  -- OLD code
data Slot = InFirst | InMiddle | InLast -- newer code
```

Why do you think we decided that the second code was an improvement over the first?

Finally, here is a bit of code from some of my day job stuff.  It uses the `newtype` syntax that augustss mentioned,

```
newtype Role = Role { fromRole :: Text }
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

newtype KmClass = KmClass { fromKmClass :: Text }
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

newtype Lemma = Lemma { fromLemma :: Text }
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Here you'll notice that I've done the curious thing of taking a perfectly good `Text` type and then wrapping it up into three different things.  The three things don't have any new features compared to plain old `Text`.  They're just there to be different.  To be honest, I'm not entirely sure if it was a good idea for me to do this.  I provisionally think it was because I manipulate lots of different bits and pieces of text for lots of reasons, but time will tell.

Can you see what I'm trying to get at?

Comment: Yes :). It's more clear in the code where we don't see the type's name and it has more meaning. But let's say that you wan't to use `a && b` with `a` and `b` of type `UseCache`; you have to rewrite `(&&)`, and all the other `Bool` functions you want to use. Something could would be the ability to write `deriving (Bool)` in the definition of `UseCache`.

Comment: I'm pleased my random grab-bag of examples and “see? see?” was comprehensible! I guess trying to express myself a bit clearly, sometimes it's useful to have different types (A) for cases where it would help avoid errors (B) for greater clarity.

It's not always cut and dry (trade-offs everywhere).  And you rightly pointed out one trade-off being the loss of convenient functions written for that particular type.  It's one of those cases (for me) anyway where your sense of what's right/wrong keeps shifting.

Also, have a look at the [Boolean package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Boolean)

Comment: `Bool` could be an instance of `Boolean`. Or `Bool` could not exist at all... Or just being used in `Boolean`.